# cannot get img from images folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Real path to `03.png` is:

```
public_html/wp-content/themes/discovery/images/03.png
```

footer.php (placed inside theme root):

```
<img id="smoothup" src="images/03.png" alt="top">  
<img id="smoothup" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>images/03.png" alt="top">  
<img id="smoothup" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>images/03.png" alt="top">  
<img id="smoothup" src="<?php get_bloginfo('template_url');?>images/03.png" alt="top">
```

In each case console says:

```
GET http://matria63.netai.net/images/03.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my .htaccess file, placed in public_html

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /
```

I tried with various file/folders permissions - `755 - 744 - 644` - without success.

Any help.

Comment: @Starkeen, this is my `htaccess` file. I can't see anywhere in the wordpress help that I need to write something in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<img id="smoothup" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/03.png';?>" alt="top">
```